# How can I access all running queues in the system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

I'm learning about the scheduler, and doing various hacks just to understand how data structures are organized. Now I'm trying to understand how the running queues of the scheduler are organized. So given a process I figured that I can find its running queue. But I just want to iterate over all running queues. How can I do this?

Comment: You tried tracing the runqueue using init_task?

Comment: No, how would I do that? What do you mean by tracing?

Comment: In linux kernel there is a variable names init_task which basically is the header of the runqueue link list. Using this header, try traversing the runqueue. Also which kernel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using kernel latest 1.17.2. So what you are sating is that I can take a pointer to the init_task, use with `init_task->se.group_node` and get a pointer to the main hashtable?

Comment: Are you sure about the kernel version? As far as I know the current stable linux version is 3.17.3.
https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: Well it probably was updated since I last downloaded it. Anyway I does it make such a big difference?

Comment: Yes. If you are using the version stated before, then loads has changed. I think in some version of the kernel a new scheduler itself was added. Also if you are interested in viewing the running processes try viewing the /var/log/syslog file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong.
Each processor has only **one** queue (it is organized as double-linked list) for running processes. But there can be more processes on the systems. One task may begin on one processor, then scheduler switches the context or  this task go to sleep and migrate to another processor and finish their work there.

In order to see tasks on processor one may use **for_each** macro in simple kernel module.

Comment: You are almost right, there are two running queues pre-CPU (one working and one for the expired tasks). Anyway, which `for_each` do you mean? There are a lot of them.

Comment: For example.
If you take a look at https://github.com/0xDen/unptrace/blob/master/unptrace.c in function "static int thread( void * data )" you might see the loop - **list_for_each** macro there is used to iterate tasks.

Comment: I thought about that. This approach gives me tasks, not running queues, it also gives me all the not runnable tasks, which belong to no running queue. In addition, how would I know if there is another running queue that is (by chance) empty at the time I run the module?

Comment: Unfortunately now I don't have any answers. But one idea is to investigate scheduler code.